# Assembly compiling error on PCSpim simulator

Tags: assembly, mips, pcspim

i'm new to assembly and i'm studying it applied on MIPS. 
My university teacher gave us some codes. Here there is one.

```
.data 0x100020000
dati1: .word 0xC000, 0xF000A000, 0x8000FFFF, 0x23150001, 0x0
.text
main:
sub1: move $t0, $zero
      la $t1, dati1
ciclo1: lw $t2, 0($t1)
         move $t3,$t2
         bne $t2, $zero, dopo1a
         ori $t4, $zero, 1
         beq $zero, $zero, dopo1b
dopo1a: slt $t4, $zero, $t2
dopo1b: bne $t4, $zero, dopo1c
        nor $t3, $t3, $t3
        addi $t3, $t3, 1
dopo1c: sw $t3, 32($t1)
        addi $t1, $t1, 4
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        slti $t4, $t0, 5
        bne $t4, $zero, ciclo1
        jr $ra
```

When i try to compile it with PCSpim simulator it gaves out an error:

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000000
Bad address in data/stack read: 0x00020000
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000004
Bad address in text read: 0x00000004
```

NOTE: I have cleared registers in PCSpim. Also in Simulator-> Set Run Parameters i have as address or label to start program: 0x00400000. ( In another stackoverflow question my same problem got solved by this because the address was 0x00000000 ). Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: that's not compilation error. That looks like runtime error. And it looks like the CPU went for instruction at address 0, even if you did set start as 0x00400000. Make sure you don't "run" the code, but just compile, and then single-step first instruction + see where it does point. The SPIM family may have some extra setting like "start at main when defined", turn that ON (I think there's something like that in MARS simulator, which is different from SPIM, but they try to supply similar simulation and environment, so they are quite interchangeable for the very basics of MIPS assembly).

Comment: but for whatever reason your simulator either starts, or gets to address 0. Figure out whether it's at the start, or after the code did run (not terminating properly) by single stepping in debugger, then try to figure out why the setting of start address didn't work, if it starts at 0. Maybe try even different versions of SPIM, or MARS just to get more experience and skill.

Comment: @Ped7g my start address is 0x00400000. I have checked it when clearing registers and also when loading the assembly file. In PCSpim i don't have an option to compile but i have only the run icon to run the code. Also i can't find start at main when defined or an option like that in preferences.

Comment: @Ped7g i have tried to run a simple code which is from a YT channel, as the code is supposed to do, the registers values change. I think it's something in my program.

Comment: your SPIM simulator variant has very likely debugger too, instead of run there should be some way to step over single instruction. The code you posted ends with `jr  $ra` and there's not `jal` instruction, or some other instruction setting up `ra` register value, so it is highly likely still zero when the code does reach that point, jumping to PC=0 causing the exception. SPIM/MARS has syscall v0=10 to terminate code. Maybe check first some working examples directly targetting SPIM/MARS, learning some basics about MIPS CPU, then it will be easier to understand what's happening.

Comment: looks like your lector gave you some incomplete instructions, what to do with those code examples and how to run them. (and if PCSPIM really does not have debugger, consider trying out some other SPIM frontend, or switch to MARS, can't imagine any problem for the basic stuff, maybe later if the lector would require you to use something SPIM-specific, that may fail in MARS, but generally MARS is more advanced (but I dislike it for various other reasons, like being written in Java and a bit in sloppy way, it's not high quality SW... although certainly good enough for students and usable)

Comment: 0x100020000 is a 36-bit address. I'm not sure why the assembler even allowed that. You should just remove that part altogether, i.e. just use `.data` without specifying an address.